# Pubnub reply from external php file

Tags: javascript, php, pubnub

I have a small dice game where i want to have a lobby so you can play it online against eachother using pubnub. 
Now i want to save how many players there are in every lobby with an external php document. so i used AJAX to send the `name` and `amount`variables to `post.php`. 
post.php writes a file and adds wichever payer that joins to the file. now i need to let the user know how many people are in the lobby so i wanted to reply with pubnub the amount of people joined.

```
PUBNUB.publish({
    channel: 'lobby',
    message: <?php echo "$people";?>
});
```

but `post.php` doesnt send the reply. 
I guess that is because javascript is client sided and there isnt a client that opens it. does anyone know a way to fix this or maybe a suggestion what i can do better?
(I know its nothing wrong with the javascript code because it works if i open `post.php` in my browser)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi there!  You have a few things needed to make your day brighter.  You want **Presence**: http://www.pubnub.com/how-it-works/presence/ and you'll want the **PubNub PHP SDK**: http://www.pubnub.com/docs/php/php-sdk.html  With PubNub Presence, you can collect *Occupancy* and a **List of Users**.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st comment above it the right answer. It is a matter of proper design.

You have a few things needed to make your day brighter. You want Presence: pubnub.com/how-it-works/presence and you'll want the PubNub PHP SDK: pubnub.com/docs/php/php-sdk.html With PubNub Presence, you can collect Occupancy and a List of Users